# Wordpress : Disabled fields in user profil

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How can I hide some fields in the user profile (/wp-admin/profile.php) without edting the Core functions of WP ?

For example, I want to hide (or disabled if i can't put it in 'Hidden') the Email field. I've make this plugin but I don't know if it's a good practice :

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Disabled Email Modification
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: Permet de désactiver la modification d'un email par un utilisateur
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: Portekoi
 * Author URI: http://blog.portekoi.com
 */

/* Hook pour 'plugins_loaded' */
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'dem_setup' ); // Disabled Email Modification

function dem_setup() {
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'dem_options' );
}

/**
 * Ajout Hack en JQuery pour rendre Disabled l'ID 'Email'
 */
function dem_options( $user ) { 
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if($screen->id == "profile"){
        ?>
        <script>
             jQuery(function () {
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    jQuery("#email").prop('disabled', true);
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are only three filters hooks in the Edit User and Profile pages: `user_contactmethods`, `admin_color_scheme_picker` and `show_password_fields`. Everything else has to be done with jQuery.

Your code can be improved targeting those specific pages on `admin_footer-$hook_suffix` and also adding a `$` as shortcut for jQuery:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'dem_setup' );

function dem_setup() {
    foreach( array('profile','user-edit') as $hook )
        add_action( "admin_footer-$hook.php", 'dem_options' );
}

function dem_options() { 
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#email,#url").prop('disabled', true);
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

One of my plugins has many options to hide stuff from the User's pages, you can check some examples of jQuery targeting [here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/many-tips-together/tags/2.3.8/inc/hooks/profile.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {

    // Remove old fields
    unset($profile_fields['aim']);

    return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

Comment: It's not only contact methods. For example, i would like to remove the check box for the Tools Bar. How can I do that?